# Restricting movement of vertices in blender

Tags: modeling, vertices

So, when I move (lets use a **cube** as an example,) I move two of the bottom vertices in said cube, it pushes the two vertices above it, causing the entire model to deform.
My question, can I lock the two top vertices in place so there is no "pushing" when I move the bottom two?

[image: Cube Example]

[image: What I DON'T want happening]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have accidentally activated the proportional editing, which has a range of influence adjustable with the mouse wheel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, and i'de like to keep it on in order to get the curvature that I want.
Is there a different way to keep prop edit on without displacing the top two?

Comment: You can do this by hiding the ones you do not want to be affected, with the **H** key and to display them use the key combination **Alt + H**
And also changing the way in which the proportional interacts, try sharp or linear